# Linear regression between columns and by index

Tags: r, lm

```
HEALTH  CONINC  MARITAL Index MARITAL2                    HAPPY
3           441 5        1            2                        3
1          1764 5        1            2                        2
2          3087 5        1            2                        2
3          3087 5        2            2                        3
1          3969 2        2            5                        1
1          3969 5        2            2                        3
2          4852 5        2            2                        2
3          5734 3        2            3                        3
```

Is there anyway to get liner regression of each column with respect to one column(eg, Happy) while breakdown by index?

Expected output would be Rsquare value:

```
HEALTH  CONINC  MARITAL Index MARITAL2   
 x       x       x         1      x      
 x       x       x         2      x
```

Tried `lapply`, while not sure how to incorporate to regress by index.

Comment: Not clear to me. Is `HAPPY` the dependent variable or independent variable? Why there are ten R^2 in the expected output?

Comment: you are right, put wrongly, supposed to have 5 columns only in output

Comment: You don't need regression for this. Just use the cor function and square the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do a single column regression by index using the `dplyr` library, collecting the R-squared values as you go:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Index) %>% 
    do(data.frame(HEALTH = summary(lm(HEALTH ~ HAPPY, data = .))$r.squared))
```

So to apply it to columns 1 to 3 and 5, you can try this:

```
l = lapply(c(1:3,5), function(i) df %>% group_by(Index) %>% 
       do(data.frame(r.squared = summary(lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(df)[i], "~ HAPPY")), data = .))$r.squared)))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working if i only want to do one column to one column, what is i want to do all regression between all columns to one column?

Comment: I haven't figured that part out yet :(

Comment: i tired df %>% group_by(Index) %>% 
    do(data.frame(HEALTH = summary(lm(HEALTH ~ ., data = .))$r.squared)), while seems like output only 2 columns

Comment: @Fiona I added something to my answer, using `lapply` as per your suggestion.  This will give you a list of the answers you seek.